# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: the return type of CallObjectMethodV does not match void android.media.AudioTrack.play()

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am trying to play audio buffer from JNI with AudioTrack

Initilizing AudioTrack object from JNI with below code

```
    jclass AudioTrack = mEnv->FindClass("android/media/AudioTrack");
    jclass AudioFormat = mEnv->FindClass("android/media/AudioFormat");
    jclass AudioManager = mEnv->FindClass("android/media/AudioManager");

    jfieldID AudioFormat_ENCODING_PCM_16BIT = mEnv->GetStaticFieldID(AudioFormat, "ENCODING_PCM_16BIT", "I");
    jint ENCODING_PCM_16BIT =mEnv->GetStaticIntField( AudioFormat, AudioFormat_ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    jfieldID AudioFormat_CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO = mEnv->GetStaticFieldID(AudioFormat, "CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO", "I");
    jint CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO =mEnv->GetStaticIntField( AudioFormat, AudioFormat_CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO);

    getMinBufferSize = mEnv->GetStaticMethodID(AudioTrack,"getMinBufferSize","(III)I");

    // int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,AdioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    minBufferSize = mEnv->CallStaticIntMethod(AudioTrack,getMinBufferSize,8000,ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO);

    //AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    jfieldID AudioManager_STREAM_MUSIC = mEnv->GetStaticFieldID(AudioManager, "STREAM_MUSIC", "I");
    jint STREAM_MUSIC = mEnv->GetStaticIntField( AudioManager, AudioManager_STREAM_MUSIC);

    jfieldID AudioTrack_MODE_STREAM = mEnv->GetStaticFieldID(AudioTrack, "MODE_STREAM", "I");
    jint MODE_STREAM = mEnv->GetStaticIntField( AudioTrack, AudioTrack_MODE_STREAM);

    audioTrackConstructor = mEnv->GetMethodID(AudioTrack,"<init>","(IIIIII)V");
    mAudioTrack = mEnv->NewObject(AudioTrack,audioTrackConstructor,STREAM_MUSIC,8000,CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,minBufferSize,MODE_STREAM);


    AudioTrack_Play =  mEnv->GetMethodID(AudioTrack,"play","()V");
    AudioTrack_Stop =  mEnv->GetMethodID(AudioTrack,"stop","()V");
    AudioTrack_Write=  mEnv->GetMethodID(AudioTrack,"write","([BII)I");
```

application with error

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: the return type of
>   CallObjectMethodV does not match void android.media.AudioTrack.play()

When i execute code

```
 mEnv->CallObjectMethod(mAudioTrack,AudioTrack_Play);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You're using `CallObjectMethod` when you should be using `CallVoidMethod`.

Comment: why do you ever want to do that? why not to call `AudioTrack.play()` directly from java layer?

Comment: @Michael Thanks it is worked :),thanks for your help (Y)

Comment: @pskink, am decoding buffer in JNI and in multiple threads :)

Comment: just use [pipe()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) function and pass the `pipefd[0]` to java layer for reading

Comment: @pskink will try that too.

Comment: @pskink can you please explain how to use pipefd[0] in java.

Comment: see `ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream`

Comment: @pskink i tried like [this](https://pastebin.com/Z41vickG).It is working,but after that application crashing **A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1, fault addr 0xefa09ff6 in tid 7880**

Comment: it works just file, this is an [output](https://pastebin.com/raw/pT3zfs1Z) when called twice - also when leaving activity there is no crash

Comment: bit if it makes problems create a pipe in C (`pipe()` function) instead of Java (`ParcelFileDescriptor#createPipe()` method)

Comment: @pskink is it possible to use this for multiple threads  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160111/discussion-between-clifford-p-y-and-pskink).

Comment: you have to use different threads - otherwise your pipe will go into deadlock

Answer (score 7):

replace this:

```
env->CallObjectMethod( mediaPlayer.GetRawObject(), setSurfaceMethodId, parms);
```

With this:

```
env->CallVoidMethod( mediaPlayer.GetRawObject(), setSurfaceMethodId, parms );
```